# Me sale el error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object al intentar obtener un json de una URL

Tags: json, .net, lista

Actualmente quiero leer un json en mi sitio web que esta creado en .NET.

Estructura del JSON.

```
{
    "xxxxx": {
        "yyyy": "1",
        "yyyy": "2",
        "yyyy": "3",
        "yyyy": "4"
    },
    "xxxxxx":{
        "yyyyy":[
            {"zzzz":2},
            {"zzzz":0},
            {"zzzz":1},

            {"zzzz":1}
        ],
        "yyyyy":[
            {"zzzz":0},
            {"zzzz":0},
            {"zzzz":2},

            {"zzzz":2}
        ],
        "yyyyy":[
            {"zzzz":0},
            {"zzzz":0},
            {"zzzz":1},

            {"zzzz":4}
        ]
    },
    "xxxxxx": {
            "yyyyyy":{
                "zzzzzzzz": "1",
                "zzzzzzzz": "2"
            },
            "yyyyyy":{
                "zzzzzzzz": "1",
                "zzzzzzzz": "2"
            }
    },
    "xxxxxx": {
            "yyyyyyy":[
                {
                    "zzzzzzz": "1",
                    "zzzzzzz": "2"
                },
                {
                    "zzzzzzz": "1",
                    "zzzzzzz": "2"
                },
                {
                    "zzzzzzz": "1",
                    "zzzzzzz": "2"
                }
            ],
            "yyyyyyyy":[
                {
                    "zzzzzzzzz": "1",
                    "zzzzzzzzz": "2"
                },
                {
                    "zzzzzzzzz": "1",
                    "zzzzzzzzz": "2"
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es el siguiente estoy usando la libreria de `using Newtonsoft.Json;`  y mis lineas de codigo que uso son las siguientes:

```
        var json = wc.DownloadString("xxxxxxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx.json");
        List<string> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
>   change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .

No quiero crear un modelo para esta operacion y quiero guardarlo temporalmente en listas de .NET

Comment: "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal". Sí vas a necesitar crear un modelo.

Comment: También puedes convertir tu `.json` en una lista. Simplemente, por `[` al principio y `]` al final del mismo.

Comment: La template que has puesto no se corresponde a un `array`, por lo que no puedes deserializarlo a una `List`. Por otra parte, si no quieres crear un tipo con esta estructura, deberás deserializarlo como `dynamic`.

Comment: Seria mas facil de leer si colocas el json con los datos verdaderos, pero estas deserializando mal. Debes tener un objeto principal y este adentro tiene un List.